# Почему компьютер под Linux работает тише, чем под Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, администрирование, ос

Всем привет, друзья! Такой вопрос: всю жизнь использую винду, но на работе коллега рассказал про Linux и его преимущества, якобы он легче и лучше обращается с железом. Решил поставить себе Ubuntu 22.04. Поставил и обратил внимание на один факт -- компьютер работает на порядок тише. Кулер практически не издаёт никаких звуков. И разряжается комп не так быстро. Кто поопытнее -- подскажите пожалуйста, а почему так?))
Всем большое спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Ядро Linux хорошо оптимизировано и на много легче, нету отслеживающих трекеров, намного меньше   мусорных процессов-программ которые навязывает  проприетарная винда

Comment: Интересно, спасибо большое за информацию. Стоит сказать, что виндой пользоваться конечно гораздо легче) За всё приходится платить..)

Comment: Windows тоже может работать тихо, если поубивать большое число процессов и ненужных сервисов, запретить автоматические обновления, убрать телеметрию и т.д. Раньше большую часть всего этого можно было сделать через DWS, говорят сейчас там вирусы. Но не беда, большую часть отключений можно сделать через PowerShell не прибегая к 3rd party. На торрентах также есть сборки где мусор вырезается, но тут тоже не свой страх и риск. Linux идёт в минималке и дальше на него всё доставляется, в Windows если что-то вырезать, можно лишиться части необходимого функционала, который трудно будет восстановить.

Comment: Да вирусы в винде майнят что-то втихую)

Comment: Вы путаете понятия "легче" и "привычнее".

Answer (score 2):

[почему windows постоянно что-то делает в фоне](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkqpqaXMtjU)

у нее защитник постоянно что-то проверяет в фоне, создает ненужную нагрузку

вообще это холивар, ни к чему такие вопросы, каждый сам для себя выбор делает осознанно, у всякого софта свои задачи

по поводу пользоваться гораздо легче - это как? [окружений рабочего стола](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Desktop_environment_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) очень много, все фломастеры разные, кому то нравится командная строка, кому то клавиатура, кому то мышей кликать, на linux есть что угодно, может быть непривычнее в сравнении с виндой,у которой ничего толком поменять нельзя? конечно принцип работы разный, везде нужны привычка и обучение

Comment: Супер, большое спасибо Вам! Очень интересно было почитать ваше мнение и каналом очень занимательным поделились)